# Kotlin: Writing large lambdas similar to Java?

Tags: kotlin

In Java, it is possible to do ->

```
someList.stream().map(x -> {
    y = doSomeOperation(x);
    z = doSomeOtherOperation(y);
    return z;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I need to convert above code to Kotlin. But in all the online tutorials, I am learning that it is only possible to have simple lambdas, like `x -> x*x` or `x->doSomethingThenReturnValue(x)`.

Is it not possible to write a complex lambda (which does some complex inline operation) like above in kotlin? I tried writing ->

```
someList.map{ x -> {
    y = doSomeOperation(x);
    z = doSomeOtherOperation(y);
    return z;
}}
```

But it threw error. Can you please tell what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: `But it threw error`. What exact error? I'd prefer not to guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is `return z`. When placed inside lambda it returns from the enclosing function, unlike in Java where it only returns from the lambda itself. So you should write either

```kotlin
someList.map { x -> 
    y = doSomeOperation(x)
    z = doSomeOtherOperation(y)
    z
}
```

or

```kotlin
someList.map { x -> 
    y = doSomeOperation(x)
    z = doSomeOtherOperation(y)
    return@map z
}
```

More details on "return" issue can be found here - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Answer (score 2):

You have written too many brackets. In kotlin, parameter definition for lambdas are set inside the bracket (see [reference documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax)).

**EDIT**: Also, return statement in lambdas is not always allowed, and when it is, its behavior is really specific. More information [in official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html).
So, your example needs to be rewritten as following:

```
someList.map { x -> 
    val y = doSomeOperation(x)
    val z = doSomeOtherOperation(y)
    // z implicitely returned as lambda result
    z
}
```

Comment: is the `return` statement necessary here? i mean in normal lambda expressions we dont write `return`, right?

Comment: You're right, the return is also wrong, you should not use it. Kotlin will automatically return the variable of the last statement, and does not allow return (well, it does *in particular cases*, but the behavior is a bit special).